# Matrix using Linked Lists. Pointer Error

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, data-structures, linked-list

I tried to implement the matrix both vertically and horizontally using linked list. The head is stored in a ponter along which you can go both horizontally and vertically.
For eg.

- Horizontally->0,0->0,1->1,0->1,1
- Vertically->0,0->1,0->0,1->1,1

The links are in this order.
I have only done the horizontal links.

Problem is that I assumed after the temp=temp1 statement, I could use one to insert the elements and one to track the inserted elements. However, I am not able to view the inserted elements after I insert them. I keep getting only junk values after the first few links. Please help.

```
struct mat{             //structure of node
    mat *hornext;
    mat *vernext;
    int num;
};

int main(void){
        mat *temp,*temp1;
        temp=new mat;
        temp1=temp;
        int data;

        cin>>data;

    for(int i=0;i<deg*deg;i++)
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter the number :";cin>>data;
            temp->num=data;
            temp=temp->hornext;
            temp=new mat;


        }

        temp=NULL;

    for(int i=0;i<deg*deg;i++)
    {   if(i%deg==0)
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<temp1->num<<" ";
        temp1=temp1->hornext;
    }
}
```

Comment: The assignment `temp=temp->hornext` does not do what you think it does, not that it matters since you overwrite `temp` in the next statement. Try doing it with pen and paper first, getting the algorithm right there. Then try to implement it. And when you have problems use a debugger to step through the code while monitoring variables and their values. Lastly, remember that uninitialized data have *indeterminate* values, and you never initialize `hornext` or `vertnext` anywhere, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, your comment helped me understand what was wrong.